# receiving emails with python api O365

Tags: python, python-3.x, office365, email-attachments

I am just starting out in Python and I am trying to accomplish a manual task I have heard is on the simpler side to accomplish with python. My company uses Office 365 for their emails and I want to retrieve an email attachment and store it locally so  I can save time . So far have established how to send a simple email, call the names of the folders in my account but I cannot figure out how to read any specific email .

my idea goes a little like this ,

```
from O365 import Account, message,mailbox

credentials =  ('username', 'given password')

account = Account(credentials)
mailbox = account.mailbox()
mail_folder = mailbox.inbox_folder()
mail_folder = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name='Inbox')
print(mail_folder)
#_init__(*,parent= Inbox, con=None,**kwargs)
Message_body = message.body()
message.get_subject('email subject here!')
print(Message.body)
```

right now I am lost and trying anything within the O365 documentation page but the message module does not have the attribute subject according to how I am using it . Any guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 5):

From your example - it's not clear if you are authenticated or not...

If you are then you will be able to list the mailbox folders. In the case below - you can access the inbox and then list the sub-folders:

```
from O365 import Account, Connection,  MSGraphProtocol, Message, MailBox, oauth_authentication_flow

scopes=['basic', 'message_all']
credentials=(<secret>, <another secret>)
account = Account(credentials = credentials)

if not account.is_authenticated:  # will check if there is a token and has not expired
    account.authenticate(scopes=scopes)

account.connection.refresh_token()mailbox = account.mailbox()
inbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name='Inbox')
child_folders = inbox.get_folders(25)
for folder in child_folders:
    print(folder.name, folder.parent_id)
```

This part will allow you to list folders (and also messages).

If I look at your code - it looks as though you are trying to do both?

Try doing something like the following to get the hang of paging through your inbox:

```
for message in inbox.get_messages(5):
    if message.subject == 'test':
        print(message.body)
```

Note that I'm looping through the first 5 messages in the inbox looking for a message with subject 'test'. If it finds the message - then it prints the body.

Hopefully this will shed a little light.

Comment: This comment really helped my approach . I just switched laptops though and have been re configuring my work environment. I will mark the answer as helpful as soon as I get everything setup.

Comment: Glad that it helps...

I've done some more since this and found that the documentation is a "bit" out of date and sometimes refers to the old version of the API instead of the new. 

I've asked for some information on the attachments part of messages and the developers will update things in due course:)

Incidentally - (this is no surprise but even so) if you try to access and app that is registered on to a different account than that of your laptop - it won't work. You need to give the app Service Account privs. This is something that I'm looking at right now.

Comment: @ChrisMellor Whenever we get read mail from API in that the mail size calculated by adding attachment size also ?

Comment: @Mayur - I'm sorry - I don't understand the question.